# Qt - Get position of rectangle within widget after translate()

Tags: qt, qwidget, qpainter

I want to get the coordinates of a QRect or QPoint within a widget to determine if that object is overlapping the edge and would be drawn outside of the widget.

The following program is just a testprogram to show my problem. There is a window in which then a black rectangle is drawn.
By using translate() of QPainter I move the coordinatesystem. After that I cant get the correct coordinates of the rectangle.

I could keep track of all coordinate system manipulations (translate(), rotate(), scale()) but thats not a nice solution. Is there an easier way to get the position of the Rectangle in relation to the top left corner of the widget?

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <iostream>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)     
    : QWidget(parent) 
{

}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) 
{   
    QPainter painter(this);     
    painter.translate(width() / 2, height() / 2);

    QRect rectangle(100, 50, 200, 100);

    std::cout << "width(): " << this->width() << "\theight(): " << this->height()
              << "\trecLeft X: " << rectangle.x() << "\trecTop Y: " << rectangle.y()
              << std::endl;
    //Output: width(): 960  height(): 432   recLeft X: 100  recTop Y: 50
}
```

What I woul like to get is:

`recLeft X: 580(width()/2+100)  recTop Y: 266(height()/2+50)`

Comment: Are you sure that painter's translation effects the rectangle coordinates too?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the transformation matrix of the painter and apply it to your rectangle. It should be something like this:

```
QTransform trans= painter.combinedTransform();
QRect transformed = trans.mapRect(rectangle);
```

Comment: A `QRectangle` is actually mapped into a `QPolygon`. In this case you may use its `boundingRect`.

Comment: You can drop the `QPolygon` constructor, there's a `map` overload that takes a `QRectangle` and returns a `QPolygon`.

Comment: I get an ambiguous call to overloaded function in Qt 5.9 MSVC2017 with `map(rectangle)`. But just found out about `mapRect`